# Segueing to a different tab in a UITabController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I am trying to segue data from my "create a party" form into my second "Find Parties" tab.

Here is a screen shot of my main story board:

[image: main story board]

my code for the create a party controller:

```
import UIKit

struct party {
    var name: String
    var location: String
    var description: String
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionField: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var newParty = party(name: "", location: "", description: "")

    @IBAction func create(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        newParty = party(name: nameField.text!, location: locationField.text!, description: descriptionField.text!)
        nameField.text = ""
        locationField.text = ""
        descriptionField.text = ""
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPartyList", sender: newParty)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationViewController : SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        destinationViewController.parties.append(newParty)
    }

}
```

Code for the find parties tab:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var partyTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        partyTable.delegate = self
        partyTable.dataSource = self

        // updates the table of users everytime submit is clicked
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.partyTable.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

     var parties = [party]()

    // creates the number of cells in the table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return parties.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Make table cells the show the user name
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = parties[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    // Allows the user to swipe and delete people from the table and also the users array
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            // delete the person in users array
            parties.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            // delete the cell from the table
            partyTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }


}
```

currently my segue just takes me directly to the "Find Parties" view controller with no way back, and not to the tab. what do I need to change in my segue to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a segue in this case, just switch tabs programatically:

```
@IBAction func create(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    newParty = party(name: nameField.text!, location: locationField.text!, description: descriptionField.text!)
    nameField.text = ""
    locationField.text = ""
    descriptionField.text = ""
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 // 2nd tab
}
```

To pass information along, you can do something like this:

```
let navVC = tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as! UINavigationController
let rootVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as! SomeViewController
rootVC.someData = myData
```

Comment: Am I able to do something like this: let secondVC = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1]
        secondVC.parties.append(newParty)

Comment: Should be able to, give it a go. You'll need to cast that VC though e.g  let secondVC = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as! PartiesViewController. In order to get access to those custom properties. Updated answer!

Comment: I guess I understand that, but I also have the nav view controller in there and that confusing me as to what controllers are what. Like is my nav controller the second tab, and that holds the other views?

Comment: It's the same process really. Grab the first VC from the nav controller. My code isnt meant for copy/paste. You'll want to do the appropriate checking and that there are controllers actually at those indexes. See further edit.

Comment: I get that, I just wasn't sure if you had to do multiple VCs or not, but now it works like a charm

Comment: Glad I could help!